# How to get a list of queryset and make custom filter in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have some codes like this:

```
cats = Category.objects.filter(is_featured=True)
for cat in cats:
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(score>=10, category=cat).order_by("-pub_date")[:10]
```

But, the results just show the last item of cats and also have problems with where ">=" in filter. Help me solve these problems. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not appending to `entries` on each iteration of the for loop, therefore you only get the results of the last category.  Try this:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(score__gte=10, category__is_featured=True).order_by("-pub_date")[:10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start by reading the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#ref-models-querysets) on this subject. However, just to get you started, the `filter()` method is just like any other method, in that it only takes arguments and keyword args, not expressions. So, you can't say `foo <= bar`, just `foo=bar`. Django gets around this limitation by allowing keyword names to indicate the relationship to the value you pass in. In your case, you would want to use:

```
Entry.objects.filter(score__gte=10)
```

The `__gte` appended to the field name indicates the comparison to be performed (`score >= 10`).